# Does it cost universities less to teach online?

Tags: university, tuition

[As more colleges stay online, students demand tuition cuts](https://apnews.com/b33f36db3569ea43ff9126a45ae5afd7)

The article talks about students demanding tuition cuts because online classes are less effective, and because lots of things they pay for are no longer relevant (such as campus transport). It notably doesn't say if it is actually cheaper for the university to teach online. If it isn't cheaper, then if the university cuts tuition fees it would have to make up the shortfall from somewhere.

Is it cheaper for universities to teach online than in-person?

Comment: Only on a long term, when they can sell the lecture halls. What they save now on heating and cleaning and postponing renovations, they spend on digital infrastructure and licenses.

Comment: Yes, when they can get rid of all the faculty and use AI to create, control and grade all assessments. Unless they don’t have any assessments so once you pay the fee you get the qualification.

Comment: Research anyone? What happened to my cyclotron? My chem lab?

Comment: @Buffy now you start to highlight the real issues to the question... Unless research is only to be done by companies who can afford it who then control the results for those who can pay or those they “like” - sounds like a film...

Comment: I am not sure it is clear what is the actual cost of teaching as universities have many more functions than just giving lectures. Also, since the pandemic is a temporary situation, most of the cost is still there: they will not sell or rent out the buildings, libraries are still there even if they not open, people have to cut the grass on campus, administration will not be automatically fired just because originally they were assigned task related to physical presence of students. These are costs directly related to teaching at the university

Comment: The student's arguments seem to focus on the lesser quality of education, not what it costs. From their point-of-view: "students want a 25% tuition cut. Is on-line learning 25% less effective?"

Comment: @Buffy: Much, if not most, research is paid for by outside grants.  When you (typically a professor who's principal investigator on the grant application) receive a research grant, the university takes a share (30% at mine) for overhead.  The rest may go for equipment (which is typically used for other things as well), salaries & tuition grants for your student employees, and to cover part of your salary.

Comment: @jamesqf, I don't understand. How does that make online chem or physics labs possible? People need to be present for some things to happen at all. And if facilities are sold off, how do those things happen?

Comment: @Buffy: Perhaps I misunderstood your comment.  I thought you were asking about who pays for the research facilities.  It's not student tuition, at least not to any great extent.  As for many of the research facilities, most people using them don't actually need to be present.  A lot of the work can be done remotely, and was even prior to COVID.

Comment: How could it not? At the most basic level, a hall has to be lit and heated and a teacher has to be paid to lecture, every time… On-line even if lighting and heating the video studio costs more than the hall, those are one-off costs.

Short-term, the teachers still have to be paid full salary and what happens when the college recognises that a straight lecture need never be repeated?

Sure, a follow-up Q&A needs the prof's presence and in your experience, what roughly are the proportions of "talk and chalk" and "Q&A" in an average lecture session?

Comment: @jamesqf The *hard* sciences can hardly be done remotely. No sensible education in chemistry, physics, biology is possible without hands-on work, and 90% (my own guess) of the scientists must be able to spend a significant part of their time in the lab, getting their hands dirty. The situation is not much different with many of the engineering species.

Comment: Khan Academy services significantly more students for significantly less cost.

Comment: @Buffy _How does that make online chem or physics labs possible?_ People have been trying to create computer-simulations for and of undergrad lab activities for 25 years now... But the question/link is about moving towards online-only, in which case there are no in-person labs needed **by definition** and those resources could in principle be sold (or at least mothballed). Of course, the resulting degree may lose some accreditation...

Comment: @LouKnee, I'm sure there are attempts, but fear they will fail. There is something about "hands on" in a physics lab, for example, that lets you develop and refine a technique. Some learn to be better at experimentation through the touch and feel (and refinement of adjustment) that I doubt you can recreate online. There is more to such things than just understanding the theory.

Comment: @Buffy, indeed: note my use of "trying" and " lose some accreditation"! My point is that "on-line **only**" removes the need for on-site teaching labs **by definition**. "Can you run a valid Physics (say) degree purely online?" is a different (and valuable) question. IIRC the Open University used to run intensive (one week?) on-site teaching lab sessions for its science degrees. OTOH I'm unconvinced by Karl's "90%" - I'd guess at 50% and falling given how many how many PG/postdocs I see just sitting at a computer doing simulation and/or analysis (but I'm clueless re. chemistry/biology).

Comment: @Karl: I have to disagree.  I got my physics BS without a whole lot of lab time.  (Other than computer lab, and since I have roughly 1000 times as much computing power in my home system as the entire physics department had back then, I don't see it as a major issue.)  Besides, I don't believe anyone's suggesting giving up physical labs entirely, just postponing them until the current pandemic situation is dealt with.

Comment: @jamesqf My "90%" statement does perhaps contain a bit of observer bias. ;-) In chemistry (Germany), you log about 2k hours of lab time before you start on your diploma/master thesis, 1.5k if you go for all theoretical chemistry options available. And you need to sync up the lab time and theoretical education. Firstly because they are (or should be!) strongly interdependent, and secondly you wreck students if you cram all the labs for a bachelor degree into 25 10h/d weeks. Which would be the inevitable result of closing the labs for a year.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There are two possible interpretation of your question, which lead to different answers.

1. Consider a University, which made a strategic choice to teach all/most of their courses fully/mostly online. Assuming they had a good team to properly consider the administrative and academic issues and to prepare high quality courses. A prominent example in the UK is [Open University](http://www.open.ac.uk/).  There are no/small costs for Estates. The costs for salaries is roughly the same or slightly smaller (staff still benefits from saving commute costs and opportunity to live in cheaper more distant areas). As a consequence, their bills are smaller and they can charge less for their courses. Today, a BSc in Maths at the Open University costs [£6k](http://www.open.ac.uk/courses/maths/degrees/bsc-mathematics-q31#fees-and-funding) per full-time year while a similar course at U Essex costs [£9k](https://www.essex.ac.uk/courses/ug00269/1/bsc-mathematics). The answer is **yes**.
2. Now, suppose a normal University like the University of Essex is suddenly forced to move teaching online. Their Estates bill remains more or less the same (Estates remain on the balance and require maintenance). The salaries remain the same. Additional funds are required to develop the necessary IT infrastructure for online delivery, equip academics with all they need for teaching from home, train staff and/or recruit extra specialists to re-develop courses for online delivery (e.g. develop substitutions for labs, etc). In this situation, the urgent switch to online teaching actually costs more, so the answer is **no**.

Comment: I think you have left out many of the costs at OU. For example, they use BBC to produce materials and that is unlikely to be free, though it might be subsidized. Also, they provide a robust distributed system of TA/tutors for students. There may be differences in government subsidies between OU and Essex as the whole UK system is still heavily subsidized though no longer free to students.

Comment: According to our University administration, the subsidies from government are mostly negligible. However, with or without subsidies, I believe my main point still stands -- urgent switch to online delivery is much more expensive than a planned development.

Comment: Yes, your main message is certainly valid.

Comment: It might also be worth adding that most providers of remote tuition will tell you that preparing high quality, effective, remote tuition take more time than in person delivery because more effort and creativity needs to be spend on encouraging and assessing engagement.

Comment: @IanSudbery and the institutions don’t pay for one to rewrite the material so it works online - they just say get it done... then hammer you when the students are not happy.

Comment: Indeed. In recognition of the extra work associated with rewriting materials, we are getting some recognition in our work load monitoring system for the extra effort, but given that we already average 120% workload, and no work is being taken away from us, it doesn't seem very helpful.

Comment: The OU will be offering far less in terms of contact time online. And I mean FAR less. You've also missed out the fact that UK Universities (which do not operate at a profit) have lost valuable income streams which subsidised the teaching - namely income from conferences, hospitality and accommodation.

Answer (score 47):

Consider [the University of California system](https://www.ucop.edu/operating-budget/_files/rbudget/2015-16budgetforcurrentoperations_.pdf) as an example: of its core funds expenditures, three quarters goes to employees, and most of the rest is student financial aid. Only 6% of the costs go to equipment, utilities, and similar.

Now, some portion of those employees would also become unnecessary if they did away with a physical campus entirely, but most are still needed to operate the organization. In the case of an institution like the UC system, remember also that much of the physical campus is also not devoted to instruction, but to research and other non-instructional activities, and these have continued in many cases (albeit with reduced capacity) through the pandemic.

In short: in the near term, most universities' costs are almost entirely identical while teaching online.  In the long term, even if they shed every physical aspect of instruction, the costs would not go down all that much unless the institution was radically restructured to greatly increase the numbers of students per instructor.

Comment: "Only 6% of the costs go to equipment, utilities, and similar."  That's super misleadling because it does not include the $193,000,000 for debt service (p. 17), which mostly pays for buildings.

Comment: You've also neglected the additional software, computer hardware, and technical support costs for online teaching (one university threw out a number in the millions).  In addition, UC is a very privileged university, not a typical one.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist the answer says it is an example, that does not mean it has to be typical or the most common.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov if it is true then how is that misleading? Did it say it was the only perfect solution anywhere? Did I miss that bit?

Comment: @Solar Mike I think it's implicit that the example is meant to be somewhat typical. What's the point of discussing a general question using a complete outlier?

Comment: @Anonymous Physicist but the debt still has to be served until the buildings are sold, which isn't going to happen soon.

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica a complete outlier? based on what? they may have more students alone than 4 or 5 other places combined and could therefore a better example... But that is not the point of the question...

Comment: Hmmm. What would an online R1 look like? Math would probably work. High Energy Physics? BioChem? My guess that this is an infeasible structure.

Comment: @Buffy Many high energy experimental physicists would not notice a difference in their research if their campuses ceased to exist.  Many have not had on campus labs for over a decade.  Plenty of other experimental physicists would have issues.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Yes, university accounting is complex. For example, buildings typically get tied to capital campaigns, which decrease their effective cost, and universities incorporating medical school generally have the medical campus in its own entirely separate budget system.  But the dominant cost remains the people: that $193B of debt service is less than 3% of the core funds, and the per-professor additional IT resources necessary for teaching online are likewise trivial compared to the cost of that professor.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist *Many high energy experimental physicists would not notice a difference in their research if their campuses ceased to exist*.  The graduate students and other staff with both feet on the ground (*i.e.* not 30k feet up) would notice.

Comment: This answers is hard to interpret without knowing what are "core funds", what other funds are there, and how are those others spent?

Comment: @usul The core funds are the ones associated with the core educational mission of the university. They are a minority of total funds, but most of the rest are largely independent financial entities with restricted funding such the hospital system, auxiliary operations like theaters, museums, and extension schools, government contracts, etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_California_finances#Annual_budget

Answer (score 13):

**It probably depends on the course**

A major cost of offering an undergraduate Biology course (and presumably other science and engineering courses I have less experience of) is practicals. These consume expensive materials, and require substantial additional support in the form of PhD students who are paid to assist in the laboratory, as well as taking multiple technicians and academic staff to deliver the classes.

There is no online equivalent to these practical elements, and so their absence likely represents a substantial saving to the university, and their loss is a significant deficit in the education such students are receiving.

For other courses, such as Mathematics, teaching is likely no cheaper and probably actually requires additional time from the teaching staff compared to in-person teaching. Since these staff are salaried they probably aren't being paid by the hour anyway, I leave debating whether this is really a "cost" to other people who are fond of arguing.

**But any analysis of the cost of teaching is missing the point**

The amount universities charge for a degree is down either to government regulation (as in the UK) or the market value of a degree to the student but either way the university is not totting up a value for the education delivered and charging the student an itemised bill for that; it is deciding what income it need, or can get, and is charging accordingly.

(Note: since these seems directed at the current situation rather than Online in general, I am considering only the costs of a traditional university providing temporary online teaching not the comparison to full distance learning as a long term decision.)

Comment: I was at a university that cancelled the physics department completely as it was **so** expensive compared to offering a management degree course - cost of labs, hi-tech equipment and space. Students that can be crammed into a 400 seat lecture theatre for 2 hours and then left with reading until the lecture next week are a cheaper source of money compared to 20 physics or engineering students that spend 23 or 24 hours per week in lectures, labs and supervised project work.

Comment: Can you support the claim that consumables for labs are a “major cost” in a biology department?  It certainly *is* a cost but I’ll bet this is dwarfed by faculty salary.

Comment: @SolarMike presumably the funding formula from government to universities should reflect this difference in costs..

Comment: In my biology department at least, the biggest two costs of teaching practicals is 1) The rent we pay to the university for the lab space. This nominally covers not just the cost of maintinance, but also the cost of replacement at end-of-life 2) The salaries of the full-time, permanent, teaching-lab technicians 3) The depreciation on the equipment. All these costs continue whether you are using them or not. The cost of consumables is actaully only a very small part.

Comment: I believe that strictly speaking, the UK government only sets a maximum tuition fee (for England and Wales), and universities are free to ask less if they want.

Comment: @gerrit: In theory, yes, in practice almost every degree is charged at £9k.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is cheaper. You don't have to pay for facilities, you don't have to pay for staff to service those facilities, you don't have to pay for utilities and maintenance on the same. You can pay some instructors less because they work from home. Students don't need to live on campus so you don't need to build dorms and offer scholarships for them. Generally cost of living is cheaper for students, so even off-campus students require less financial support.

But this stuff only applies if you are a remote university to begin with. If you already have facilities and staff geared towards on-campus learning, you're not going to magically save money because nobody is using them. Instead you'll be wasting money on expensive facilities nobody can use. Sure you can turn off power and save a few dollars there, but the bank will still come to collect interest on the loan. And generally there's all the money you invested before, with the expectation that you will be able to get use out of it, which now becomes a sunk cost.

As far as lowering tuition though, this is an indirect factor at best. Elite universities are not the kind of industry where the market efficiently competes for a few percentage points of profit above cost. Many students do not consider elite universities a commodity, and would not switch simply to save a few dollars, in the same way way people won't stop buying Apple product just because there are cheaper competitors. There is tremendous brand value. This isn't true for all students, and some surely *will* rethink their education path, but elite universities have highly competitive admissions with many more times people applying than get in. So you could say there is a huge artificial shortage of spots at elite universities, and slightly shrinking the market will not reduce demand much.

On the contrary, no-name universities are usually treated as generic commodities, and we may see prices come down. These universities have already had cheaper tuition before Covid, as their students shop around more and even consider (gasp) not going to university altogether. Their admissions are also not that competitive. But many of these universities already have been doing distance learning, and others might not find it easy to switch over just for a year only to switch back again after.